# ASP.NET MVC3 app - HTTP Error 404.7 for route with double dot

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Routing:

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "Dashboard_default",
            "Dashboard/{controller}/{action}/{jobName}",
            new { action = "Index", controller = "Dashboard", jobName = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

But for Route

http://localhost/candidate/Dashboard/Overview/Show/sdfdsf.xx.dd

I recieve:

HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension.

In the same time, route

http://localhost/candidate/Dashboard/Overview/Show/sdfdsf.xx

Gives right response.

I assume some issue with IIS, have anyone seen that before?

Comment: I would imagine your route never reaches that `MapRoute` because `candidate` != `Dashboard`?

Comment: no, candidate is just the name of virtual folder

Comment: I have seen similar issues, but not with .dd extension. IIS forbids things like ".ascx", ".resx", ".master" etc to be part of route, and one of these extensions is also ".dd" (disk dupe? :)) 
I have described removal procedure in my answer (I trust it is not needed, but just in case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To allow that particular url, in your web.config you could add this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions>
          <remove fileExtension=".dd" />
        </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Otherwise, you could add a `<clear />` inside of fileExtensions to allow any file to be routed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .Net 4.0, give this a shot in your system.web section of your web.config:

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

More explanation here:
http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx

More info:
http://weblogs.asp.net/carldacosta/archive/2010/04/24/tweaking-a-few-url-validation-settings-on-asp-net-v4-0.aspx

As I understand it, dots are treated as a literals in the routing definition.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/04/10/upcoming-changes-in-routing.aspx

Comment: I'm wondering if it's even making it past IIS into the routing engine.  Have you tried a catch-all route?  It should at least help determine if the issue is IIS vs MVC routing.

Comment: Also, have you tried this:  http://www.west-wind.com/wconnect/WebLog/ShowEntry.blog?id=697

Answer (score 0):

You need a catch all on the last param for the routing to work.

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Dashboard_default",
            "candidate/Dashboard/{controller}/{action}/{*jobName}",
            new { action = "Index", 
                            controller = "Overview", 
                            jobName = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
```

Comment: Just noticed it's missing candidate in the path, add had controller twice. You also have too many segments, they don't match up.

Comment: Where does Overview fit into it? Is this a fixed string?

Comment: "Just noticed it's missing candidate" - candidate is the name of virtual folder, not the part of Route

Comment: So if Overview is the name of the controller whats Dashboard? Is that also a virtual folder? Updating to reflect current understanding.

Answer (score 0):

.dd extension is one of denied file name extensions by default in IIS. You can remove it by going to inetmgr -> web site -> application (candidate) -> Request Filtering (in IIS section) -> find .dd under File Name Extensions tab and remove it.

**EDIT**

Described action will automatically add next section to web.config (I see that someone did that and posted it as new answer):

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <fileExtensions>
                <remove fileExtension=".dd" />
            </fileExtensions>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```